# update geo point in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update a document in Elastic search 1.7 using update API.
I want to update the geo-point value. While calling the update API i am trying to update the geo-point and a field. I am not able to update the geo-point here.

Create an Index:

```
    curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/"
```

Create Mapping

```
    curl -X POST -d '{"my_type": 
{"properties": 
{"id": {"type": "string"}, 
"status":{"type":"string"},
"location": {"type": "geo_point","lat_lon":true}}}}'
http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type
```

Insert

```
    curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"Id": "125",
"status": "LIVE",
"location": {
"lat": 10.4839,
"lon": 10.34904
}}' "http://localhost:8080/{endpoint}"
```

Update

```
    curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"oldUniqueId":"2location9",
"Id": "125",
"status": "LIVE",
"newLocation": {
"lat": 15.4839,
"lon": 15.34904
},
"oldLocation": {
"lat": 10.4839,
"lon": 10.34904
}}' "http://localhost:8080/{endpoint}"
```

Logic to update(here i take the old and new loc as data and try to update location field)

```
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.index("my_index");
updateRequest.type("my_type");
updateRequest.id(myUpdate.Id());
try {
updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder()
.startObject()
.field("status", "CLOSED")
.field("location",myUpdate.getNewLocation())
.endObject());
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return myUpdate;
}
```

While running this i am not able to update the location . I have already set lat_lon to true in the mapping and tried passing "location.lat"=10.435 as data to update. This added a new field but did not update the existing one.

Getting an exception like this:

```
     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"Location(lat=15.4839"
! at 
sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
! at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
! at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
! at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint.resetFromString(GeoPoint.java:68) ~[merchant-service-server-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoPointFieldMapper.parsePointFromString(GeoPointFieldMapper.java:551)
```